# How to bring data from external sources (mainly Restful) to HDFS?

Tags: java, rest, hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

This is more sort of design related question. I am a java developer and new to hadoop Big data world; learning hadoop in my Hortonworks HDP Sandbox (it's a single node pseudo cluster provided as VM by Hortonworks).

I have designed a Java restful api that interacts with the dummy Database I have created. The api/client will send series of "GET" request to a uri and stores the result-body as a table form (TSV) textfile in local hortonworks Unix server. From there I do copyFromLocal to HDFS for further processing.

1. Is there a open source hadoop component designed to do this, Can I design the api as a Map-Reduce jobs with number of reducers set to zero? I am looking for better alternatives.
2. Can I create a script action or java action as a oozie-work flow in Hue/HDP?

Comment: After a six months of research and continuous work in Hadoop in my spare time, I have finally figured out to execute Restful requests from map-reduce jobs / oozie jobs. Please contact me if you are in similar situation, I can maybe put the details & source code in github.

Comment: Could you add gist or small github example how you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your aim is to bring the data out of a Database to HDFS in the form TSV, then this can be done very easily using the [Sqoop tool](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop/sqoop/).

Sqoop is a Hadoop ecosystem component, it can directly connect to your rdbms database and can import the records of the tables with a custom delimiter. I hope this would simplify the implementation of your requirement.

Comment: thanks for the response. I have tested with sqoop with CLI only (couldnt figure out to configure oozie-workflow with hue) , which works fine. This is the case when you don't have direct access to the Database. You can access to the DB through web service call only.

Comment: If you can't interact directly with the database, how does the client know what GETs to make?  Another GET that returns a list of primary keys?

Comment: @keegan, the main reason of using restful is to authenticate the users and present only the data which he/she has access to. HTTP client has ability to send the GET request based on who has logged. There is a predefined uri + queri parameters (myApp/usersId/events/year) and the response returns data in json/xml and the data are stored as TSV: randomID + /t + xml/json + /t + timestamp + /n.

Comment: @ruben123, to solve this in simple terms ,you may enable **WebHDFS** on hadoop, and let the restful server side write the result to HDFS through WebHDFS api..let the client just invoke the rest service with username/password..and the result will be prepared by rest service and the rest service will write the result directly to HDFS through WebHDFS api...by this you skip storing the result on local fs and copying to hdfs manually...I hope this might help you..

Comment: @hserus, I did read about the WebHDFS couple of weeks ago, it seems like emerging hadoop component & excellent tool. Do you have idea of where can I find the resources/examples related to WebHDFS api for Java & the version comparability issue with other existing components in hadoop ecosystem.

Comment: [Here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html)'s a place to start.  I'll warn you though, WebHDFS performed worst than the native calls for me when I experimented with it.

Comment: Also to your #1, yes, you absolutely can have a map with no reduce (and if I were building the job to do this, that's what I would do -- Sqoop does the same thing). Just make sure not to fire up too many mappers, you don't want to bring your DAO to its knees.